# How to normalize the volume of an OPUS file

Tags: ogg-opus

Previously I was using `vorbisgain` to normalize the volume of my Ogg-Vorbis files to 89dB (default). Now that I will encode my audio files in Opus format, is there a tool equivalent to `vorbisgain` for Opus files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rgain](https://github.com/chaudum/rgain) project can do this. It's in the Debian `replaygain` package (not on Ubuntu yet, sorry), though the Debian package doesn't yet support the `.opus` extension (see its [issue 13](https://github.com/chaudum/rgain/issues/13), resolved in version 1.0.0, which comes [*after*](https://github.com/chaudum/rgain/tags) 1.3.4).

I installed the Debian package (warning, I'm running Debian Testing, not Ubuntu) and then edited `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/rgain3/rgio.py` to add `.opus` to the following stanza starting on [replaygain-1.0.0-1](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/rgain3)'s line 360:

```py
    BASE_MAP = {
        ".ogg": _simplereaderwriter,
        ".oga": _simplereaderwriter,
        ".opus": _simplereaderwriter,
        ".flac": _simplereaderwriter,
        ".wv": _simplereaderwriter,
        ".m4a": _mp4readerwriter,
        ".mp4": _mp4readerwriter,
    }
```

Alternatively, install without package management as per the rgain instructions.

Then it's just a matter of running `replaygain file.opus`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to install version 1.0.0 with [pipx](https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx): pipx install rgain3. The file to modify is then located at `~/.local/pipx/venvs/rgain3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rgain3/rgio.py`.

Answer (score 2):

**I found loudgain in the 21.04 Hirsute repos:**

Package: loudgain
Section: universe/sound
Description-en:

ReplayGain 2.0 loudness normalizer based on the EBU R128 standard
loudgain is a loudness normalizer that scans music files and

calculates loudness-normalized gain and loudness peak values according
to the EBU R128/ITU BS.1770 standard (-18 LUFS).

loudgain will embed ReplayGain 2.0-compatible metadata tags in a file
if requested but will not modify the audio data in any way.

loudgain supports the FLAC, Ogg, MP2, MP3, MP4, M4A, ALAC, Opus, ASF, WMA, WAV, WavPack, AIFF and APE audio formats. Video files with compatible audio streams are also supported.

Comment: The necessary command would be: `loudgain -s i myfile.opus`, without `-s i` the file will remain unchanged!